# Is there any way to use FFMPEG expressions in bitstream filters options?

Tags: ffmpeg, latency, bitstream

FFMPEG allows to set User Data Unregistered in SEI block with `h264_metadata` bitstream filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input/test.mp4 \
       -bsf:v             \
       "h264_metadata=sei_user_data=c5bfd5ee-b030-11ec-b909-0242ac120002+waagh" \
       -f h264              \
          test.h264
```

I know it is possible to use FFMPEG expression evaluation mechanism in filter bodies, is it possible to do that in bitstream filter bodies? More specifically, I would like to encode a current Unix timestamp into SEI block to calculate actual latency during playback.

None of my attempts to use expressions in bitstream filter bodies worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation is per-option rather than per-filter or per component type.
For sei_user_data in h264_metadata, it's not implemented.